# match single cell value with column of values for every match return those rows Google-apps-script

Tags: search, google-apps-script, match, copy-paste, multiple-instances

I have a spreadsheet with 2 tabbed sheets. I am trying to run a macro so that when the user inputs a name in B2 of the 2nd sheet, it is matched with every instance of that name in the 1st sheet, column B. I then need to copy all of the data that appears in the matched cell's rows and have that pasted in the 2nd sheet starting with cell B3.
I have limited experience with VBA, but none with JS/Google-apps-script. Any help with how to write this would be greatly appreciated! Here is my first shot:

```
function onSearch() {  
  // raw data sheet
  var original = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 2");
  // search for student sheet
  var filtered = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Student Progress Search");


  // retrieving the values in the raw data array of names
  var searchColumn = 2;
  var lr = original.getLastRow();
  var searchRange = original.getRange(2,searchColumn, lr, 1).getValues();

  // retrieving the name submitted on search
  var inputName = filtered.getRange(2, 2).getValue();

  // loop through all the names in the raw data and identify any matches to the search name
  for (var i = 0; i < lr; i++){
  var dataValue = searchRange[i];
  var r = dataValue.getRow();
  var line = [[r]]; 
  var paste = filtered.getRange(3, 3);

  // if the data is a match, return the value of that cell in the searched sheet
  if (dataValue == inputName){ return paste.setValues(line);
                        }

}

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need a macro for that? Sounds like an overkill.  This could be literally one line with the built-in QUERY function.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the built-in QUERY function would work for you. This here does exactly what you are looking for:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!B:B,"select B where LOWER(B) like LOWER('%" &B2& "%')")
```

For example, if a user enters 'joe', the function will match any entry containing 'joe', regardless of case.

Comment: Can i connect this to a button? I was going to run the macro with a "search" button

Comment: Well, you can definitely write the script that adds this formula to the target range 
 (range.setFormula(formula)) and connect it to a button

Comment: Does this fix the issue? If so, please consider marking the original question as resolved.